# Помогите с регуляркой(достать с адресса страницы данные)

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Надо достать с адреса сайта определённые данные

Адрес такого типа:

```
https://sellercentral.com/item-333/book/112-7881858-5890638/
```

нужна такая регулярка которая сможет достать данные после отрывка "book/" до следующего слеша то есть `112-7881858-5890638`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста:

```
/\/book\/([^/]+)\//i
```

---

```js
const re = /\/book\/([^/]+)\//i; 
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  console.clear(); 
  if (e.key === 'Enter')
    console.log((this.value.match(re) || [0, 'Нет совпадений'])[1]); 
});
```

```css
body  { font: 18px sans-serif; }
kbd   { padding: 0 0.3em; border: 1px solid #888; border-radius: 3px; }
input { width: 90%; font: inherit; }
```

```html
<p>Клавиша <kbd>Enter</kbd> - проверить введенную строку</p>
<input autofocus value="https://sellercentral.com/item-333/book/112-7881858-5890638/">
```

Comment: Все работает прекрасно,респект :)